# 500 ответ file_get_contents

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять причину проблемы : пишу

```
file_get_contents("http://несуществующий.ru/");
```

и получаю 500 ошибку. Если url существует, то ошибка не возникает . Где копать ?

а на другом серваке все норм

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://несуществующий.ru/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/user/data/www/dsdsdsds/_test.php on line 5
```

Comment: скорее всего, это разные настройки управления ошибками

Comment: да, верно . Это и мне понятно . Мне бы помогли конкретные советы по решению данной проблемы

Comment: display_errors и error_reporting в php.ini, в общем-то и всё

Comment: в коде прописано, но ничего не меняется ! 
`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Sarkis Allahverdian, есть доступ к php.ini ? попробуйте взять php.ini обоих серверов и сравнить через notepad++ (или любую другую программу, которые позволяют сравнить два файла), посмотрите чем отличаются конфиги. ОС одинаковые ? Шаред это или vps или еще что ?

Comment: Сравнил. Все идентично . VPS . Разные версии debian